# Unable to determine IP address from host name, The domain name does not exist

Tags: iis-7, dns, hosts

A local website is set up on a server.
The website `test.skien.kommune.no` is mapped to 127.0.0.1
The site is configured in IIS and I have added a binding.
Everything worked for a week, but today I suddenly got this error message:

```
The following error was encountered while trying to retrieve the URL: http://test.skien.kommune.no/

    Unable to determine IP address from host name "test.skien.kommune.no"

The DNS server returned:

    Name Error: The domain name does not exist.

This means that the cache was not able to resolve the hostname presented in the URL. Check if the address is correct.

Your cache administrator is webmaster.
```

The hosts-file is configured `'127.0.0.1        test.skien.kommune.no'`

Why doesn't it use the local dns-mapping in the host-file?

Comment: If you remember how you fixed this issues, can you please share the solution?

Answer (score 12):

I found that the proxy settings were my problem.

In Windows "**Control Panel**" open "**Internet Options**" and go to the "**Connections**" tab. Click the "**LAN settings**" button.

If "**Use a proxy server**" is ticked, this may be your problem too. If there are periods in the local host domain, the proxy kicks in and treats the URL as a fully qualified domain name (which it won't be able to find).

To exclude it, click on "**Advanced**" and add it to the "**Do not use proxy...**" list.

Answer (score 5):

Check for any VPN. if you have enabled any VPN in chrome then disable it.

Comment: I can't begin to thank you enough for this. I would have stripped or restored my XAMPP system if I had not seen this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting @leo est omnia's answer, it might be possible that your browser would be treating your virtual host as a fully qualified domain when proxy server is ticked.

Adding to the answer,you also have these settings for the browser you are using, like for "Chrome":
settings => advanced settings => network => change proxy settings => connections => lan settings => uncheck use proxy server.

Also, if you have done some changes in your "httpd.conf" file, if you have given "\" backslash for directory path for the default path for your local  apache files, use "/" forward slash instead, apache reads it the linux type.

Answer (score -1):

**This is the whole story**
You should not use a proxy
Your proxy may have occurred through a browser extension, or you may have saved something in the system settings